# Low Water Pressure When Kitchen Faucet is Opened Quickly

Tags: plumbing, faucet, water-pressure

I don't know how to search for this, because my searches don't turn up proper results.

This applies only to my kitchen sink and water dispenser from fridge. The downstairs bathroom and all upstairs faucets are unaffected by this. If I open the faucet too quickly, the water will trickle out. I can't get my fridge dispenser (or ice maker) to work, because those are a binary on/off.

The only way to get decent pressure is to slowly turn the faucet on. If I open it too quickly, the faucet will make a soft "pop". I have checked under the sink, and the hoses have no kinks. They don't move when the pop happens either.  There aren't any visible leaks anywhere either. Also, I have to let the water completely stop trickling before I turn it back on, or this will produce low pressure as well.

Comment: Does this affect only hot, only cold, or both? Is this a single handle faucet, or a traditional two-knob style?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it's both hot and cold water. It's a single handle faucet as well.

Comment: What happens if you turn the water to the fridge off, unhook the water line to the fridge, stick it in the sink basin, and slowly turn the valve for it on?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The hoses aren't long enough. I'd have to go pick up longer ones to test this. Do you have alternate solutions in the mean time?

Comment: What's the plumbing made from, BTW? Also, is the fridge fed through a proper tee, or a saddle valve?

Comment: I'd replace the faucet cartridge.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'm not 100% sure. The only exposed pipe is for a shutoff value for the hose outside (copper)  and the sink u-bend (PVC). The fridge is hooked up to a standard shutoff valve like the ones feeding a toilet.

Comment: @Tyson -- that's what I'd think, but the issue with the fridge has me wondering what the heck could be going on

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I think it's two problems. That needs to be proven tho but to do that we have to eliminate one first, then we can figure out the other.

Comment: @Tyson -- yeah, shotgunning the faucet cartridge may be the best way to go if they can't test the water line for the fridge.  The faucet cartridge being part of the problem would also explain why hot would be affected

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I can pick up another hose tomorrow. They're cheap enough. I can also get a cartridge for the faucet. When I hook the fridge up to the sink line, what am I testing for? Also thanks a ton for being patient!

Comment: You're testing to see if the line to the fridge has the same symptoms as the faucet